# Misaligned UV coordinates after Draco compression

Tags: three.js, blender, gltf

All extension attributes are misaligned after the very first primitive in the asset after exporting to glTF using Blender's inbuilt Draco compression.

Example: first one is good but the two next are misaligned which causes error.

```
            "extensions" : {
                "KHR_draco_mesh_compression" : {
                    "bufferView" : 0,
                    "attributes" : {
                        "POSITION" : 0,
                        "NORMAL" : 1,
                        "TEXCOORD_0" : 2,
                        "TEXCOORD_1" : 3
                    }
                }
            },
            "indices" : 4,
            "material" : 0,
            "mode" : 4
        },
        {
            "attributes" : {
                "POSITION" : 5,
                "NORMAL" : 6,
                "TEXCOORD_0" : 7,
                "TEXCOORD_1" : 8
            },
            "extensions" : {
                "KHR_draco_mesh_compression" : {
                    "bufferView" : 4,
                    "attributes" : {
                        "POSITION" : 0,
                        "NORMAL" : 1,
                        "TEXCOORD_0" : 7,
                        "TEXCOORD_1" : 8
                    }
                }
            },
            "indices" : 9,
            "material" : 1,
            "mode" : 4
        },
        {
            "attributes" : {
                "POSITION" : 10,
                "NORMAL" : 11,
                "TEXCOORD_0" : 12,
                "TEXCOORD_1" : 13
            },
            "extensions" : {
                "KHR_draco_mesh_compression" : {
                    "bufferView" : 5,
                    "attributes" : {
                        "POSITION" : 0,
                        "NORMAL" : 1,
                        "TEXCOORD_0" : 12,
                        "TEXCOORD_1" : 13
                    }
                }
            },
```

I learned that one solution could be to change the attributes within the `extensions` of the second and further primitives so they follow an incremental order. However, when dealing with a lot of objects this manual process may cause some issues as it will require a lot of manual work which may result in bugs and errors in the result.

My question is does the most recent version of `Draco` and `Three.js` have these bug fixed? **Our app is currently running on `three.js r107`**.

Answer (score 1):

Solution part 1: Yes, you should manually update `extensions._compression.attributes` so they follow a numerical order, at least [until this bug report is fixed](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Blender-IO/issues/993).

However, I'm almost certain that the reason you're still running into this problem is because you're using Three.js r107. I say this because GLTF support for `KHR_Mesh_Quantization` [was added on r111](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/pull/17923), which Blender's DRACO compression uses. Additionally, there have been substantial improvements to both DRACO and GLTF between r107 and r117. You can [see this in the changelog](https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/releases).

When updating to the newest version, don't forget to update the files for `dracoLoader.setDecoderPath()` [as outlined in the docs](https://threejs.org/docs/#examples/en/loaders/GLTFLoader).